# Triangulating a huge set of points

Tags: math, graphics, 3d, polygon

When triangulating a set of points and the number of points is huge (10 millions), you need to triangulate one chunk at time after subdividing the problem using a quad-tree or an oct-tree.

So far so good, we are now looking for a smart approach to fill the small straight gaps between each mesh. Do you know a good one?

Thanks.

Comment: do you mean tessellating in triangles? (because what you said about the mesh...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than finish by welding together the separate parts of the mesh, why not start by decomposing the point set into overlapping chunks ?  This way your problem becomes one of removing unwanted edges rather than finding missing ones, at the expense of duplicating the computation of the mesh along the borders.  This might be easier though I suspect its computational complexity is no different.

I believe that most standard approaches to triangulation can not be expected to produce the same mesh across the boundary for the two overlapping chunks.  However, I also believe (without proof) that the computation of the mesh across the boundary between (the interior of neighbouring) chunks is increasingly likely to produce the same triangulation across the boundary as the depth of the overlap increases.

Think of an existing triangulation of a set of points, and add a new point outside the hull of the existing points.  Triangulating the extended set of points will require only local (in some vague sense) adjustment of the existing mesh, in most cases.  Simlilarly, deleting a point at the edge of an existing mesh will rarely affect the triangulation at the centre of the mesh.

If this *ad-hoc* approach doesn't appeal to you, use your favourite search engine and look for *parallel delaunay triangulation*

Answer (score 0):

If the mesh is connected using linear elements (straight sides), the only way you can have gaps is if endpoints on adjacent edges aren't coincident.

You can check within some tolerance sphere whether two points should be made one, but the tolerance has to be smaller than the shortest edge in your mesh or you'll collapse elements.

The smartest thing I can think of is to parallelize the job.  Break the mesh into one chunk per thread/process and do the tolerance check on each one.

It might be a good map-reduce job.  Or perhaps GPUs and CUDA would be a good way to go.

When you calculate the distance between two points you can forgo the expensive square root and just look at the square of the distance compared to the tolerance.

Comment: We have gaps because if one point is inside a Voxel, it's not inside the adjacent one and nobody adds triangles in the middle.

Comment: How can you tell that it's "inside" and shouldn't be further subdivided?  I'm assuming that your octree/quadtree mesh generator tries to connect all the points on its first pass.  Why would any be left behind?

Comment: We are simply subdividing until we reach a predefined number of points, for example 10k. Is you see the mesh, you can easily distinguish all the subdivisions because a row/column of triangles is missing...

Comment: I don't know of a magic solution, then.  The only suggestion I can offer is to parallelize it. Break the problem into chunks that you can process separately, then weld the chunks together on the common boundary.

Comment: _"weld the chunks"_: this is the main point of my question. Do you know a good approach for this?